# Trying to sort {key: object} pairs by object property with Javascript and Underscore

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, underscore.js

```
{
  "TR":{
    "total_fans":1848,
    "country_name":"Turkey"
  },
  "US":{
    "total_fans":1097,
    "country_name":"United States"
  },
  "DE":{
    "total_fans":915,
    "country_name":"Germany"
  },
  "MX":{
    "total_fans":1148,
    "country_name":"Mexico"
  },
  "RS":{
    "total_fans":359,
    "country_name":"Serbia"
  },
  "IT":{
    "total_fans":798,
    "country_name":"Italy"
  }
}
```

I would like to sort this based on fans.  For instance, in this case it should be "TR", "MX", "US"... and so on using JS and Underscore if that helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Syntax error on your object... is that the whole object?

Comment: i edited it and i guess i messed something up, but it looks like Doorknob fixed it.  Is there a way to format it in stackoverflow without just spacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript objects are unordered, so you won't be able to sort or otherwise define a specific order.

You could convert the properties to an Array, and sort that instead, but that's about as close as you'll get.

Since it seems you want to sort by number of fans, you can do this.

```
Object.keys(myObject)
    .sort(function(a,b) {
        return myObject[a].total_fans - myObject[b].total_fans;
    }).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(myObject[key]);
    });
```

To support IE8 and lower, you'll need patches for `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach`.

And as Bruce Lim noted, this is an ascending sort. To descend, swap the operands of the `-` operator after the `return`.

```
return myObject[b].total_fans - myObject[a].total_fans;
```

Comment: he actually wants to sort by fans.

Comment: @natecraft1 changed the property to total_fans btw. It works to sort ASC. To sort DSC: return myObject[b].total_fans - myObject[a].total_fans;

Comment: +1 Whoah, nice work cookie monster!  I forgot all about `Object.keys`...which does exactly what I was trying to do myself with `Object.ownProps`, but is more standard.  Yours is clearly the best answer.

Comment: yo cookie, good stuff.  What would you name this question so that the most people who have the same issue run into it?  I am still learning the lingo ;)

Comment: @natecraft1: I think your title is very descriptive of what you were asking for. Maybe `key:value` pairs instead of `key:object`, but otherwise you've got the lingo nailed. And you probably noticed that I didn't use the `forEach` from underscore, but it would be the same, only passing the sorted array as the first argument. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting with an array:

```
var array = [];

// copy object to array
for (var x in yourObject) array.push([x, yourObject[x].total_fans]);

// sort array
array.sort(function(item1, item2) { return item1[1] - item2[1] });

// now get the keys
var keys = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) keys.push(array[i][0]);

// keys = ["RS", "IT", "DE", "US", "MX", "TR"]
```

Note that the key-getting step could be easier with `map` if you don't care about old IEs.

Answer (score 1):

No underscore is necessary if you don't care about IE < 9. Given your structure being in a variable `obj`:

```
var sorted = Object
   .keys(obj)
   .map(function(key) {
       // Put the country in the item?
       obj[key].country = key;
       return obj[key];
   })
   .sort(function(a, b) {
       if (a.total_fans > b.total_fans) {
           return -1;
       } else if (b.total_fans > a.total_fans) {
           return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   });
```

This will give you an `Array` sorted with the items having the most fans being first, and the country code added to each item in case you need that (omit if unnecessary).

Comment: jacob thanks this is an awesome answer and i learned a lot from it

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Thanks to a heated but useful exchange with Doorknob, I realized that he had an excellent point about being careful about modifying `Object.prototype`.  I modified the answer to make the extension of `Object.prototype` less intrusive by making the new method non-enumerable.  Thanks, Doorknob!

**UPDATE 2**: I realize now that the OP's wisely selected correct answer has the right of it.  `Object.keys` does exactly what my `ownProps` method (see below) does, and it's a standard (though you still have to polyfill in IE8).  I would just delete this answer since cookie monster nailed it, but I think this is a useful discussion and even though `ownProps` is redundant with `Object.keys`, it might teach someone...something.

I wrote a convenience function called `ownProps` which returns all the property names of an object (excluding properties in the prototype chain).  It's a more functional way of doing what Doorknob is suggesting above:

```
// retrieves all of the properties of an object as an array, 
// omitting properties in the prototype chain; note that we use
// Object.defineProperty so we can make this non-enumerable, thereby
// making a safer modification of Object.prototype
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'ownProps',{
  enumerable: false,
  value: function() {
    var props = []; for( var prop in this ) { 
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) props.push( prop ); 
    } 
    return props;
  }
});
```

Armed with this, you can sort your object using a custom sort function:

```
var obj = {"TR":{"fans":1848,"country_name":"Turkey"}/*...*/}

var sortedKeys = obj.ownProps().sort(function(a,b){
    return obj[a].fans - obj[b].fans;
});
```

Comment: Disagree, Doorknob.  One of the beauties of JavaScript.  Not everything Douglas Crockford says is plated in gold.

Comment: Well, let's say someone goes and does `if (someVariable.ownProps === undefined) someVariable.ownProps = ['some', 'stuff']`. Oops, your code just broke that :(

Comment: As opposed to...anything else you do?  What if I made a custom function NOT on `Object.prototype` that does that?  Someone could come along and overwrite that.

Comment: In JavaScript, there are a million opportunities to screw things up...it's part of the nature of the beast.  While I don't go willy-nilly modifying `Object.prototype` for the fine reasons you're laying down, some well-placed and sensible extensions are not the end of the world.

Comment: Actually, simply *this function existing* will break the code I gave as an example, even if the coder didn't know it even existed. Placing this into production code would be very dangerous. Also, what if someone looped over a plain object, like `o = { ... }; for (x in o) { // do stuff }`?

Comment: I'm sorry, Doorknob, I just disagree with what you are saying.  It won't break the code you you gave as example; the code you gave as an example is fragile.  Everyone knows not to use `for...in` on an object unless you check for `hasOwnProperty`.  You think my custom function is the only function/property on `Object.prototype`?  Because it definitely isn't.

Comment: "Everyone knows not to use for...in on an object unless you check for hasOwnProperty" However, if you actually try it, looping over a plain object (i.e. `for (x in {}) console.log(x);`) yields nothing. Now try adding this function and see what happens. Anyway, I have to go and this discussion is pointless, so I will stop commenting now

Comment: I don't believe this discussion is pointless, and you are raising good points.  In particular, you're right about one thing: it's probably not the smartest thing in the world to add *enumerable* properties to `Object.prototype`, and in that I will concede that you are correct.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: To throw in my 2 bits, if someone decides to extend `Object.prototype`, clearly it's up to them. However I really don't think its a great idea to suggest it to new developers without giving an explanation of what may go wrong. The `.hasOwnProperty()` fix covers part of what can go wrong, but not everything, and it's not a very DRY solution. As you said, there are lots of things that can get messed up in JS, but this one touches so much code that IMO we need to be careful suggesting it.

Comment: You're right, cookie monster and Doorknob: I was being a bit cavalier with my modification of `Object.prototype`.  It's not something to be taken lightly.  However, I do find `ownProps` is useful, and enables a more fluent/functional style, so I'm going to roll with it.  I did modify my answer to make the `ownProps` method non-enumerable, so it won't interfere with `for...in` enumerations of an object.

Comment: FWIW, *"Not everything Douglas Crockford says is plated in gold."* is a statement I can entirely agree with! ;-D

Comment: For a reference on extending native prototypes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes It still is up to the programmer to "break encapsulation" In the past google maps team had bad experience assuming what everyone should know about JavaScript: http://bolinfest.com/javascript/inheritance.php under "The Google Maps team learned this the hard way"

Answer (score -1):

### Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/az7XN/

lets say that whole your object of fans is a `fansObj`:

```
for(prop in fansObj){
   console.log(prop, fansObj[prop]);
}
```

output example: `TR, {"fans":1848,"country_name":"Turkey"  }`

before `for` circle declare array variable and push there each obj:

```
var arr = [];
for(prop in fansObj){
   console.log(prop, fansObj[prop]);
   arr.push(fansObj[prop]);
}
```

then sort:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){parseInt(b['total_fans'],10) - parseInt(a['total_fans'])});
```

`parseInt(obj,10)` will accept convert object as decimal to integer.

Now you have sorted array (depending on comparison inside sort function (a-b=desc or b-a=asc)).

Used function:

[`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: UPDATE: added sort. Fistly I wrote how you can go throw all properties in object, then added sort.

Comment: There's no need for the `parseInt`...the `total_fans` property is already a number.

Comment: @EthanBrown yeah, you are right, but I thinked that was string inside JSON, so I added parse. It even better to have integer parser, cause in javascript you can set anything to `total_fans`